# Heroku: Figuring out why your app crashed

Tags: php, logging, heroku

My App crashed for the second time in the last 7 days. It displays the Application Error for a period of about 30-60 minutes then comes back online.

This happens while I'm not working on the app (i.e. I'm not checking in any code).

How can I diagnose what went wrong? Both times I found out about the crash about an hour after it came back online, so when I do `heroku logs -n 1500` it returns things like `GET` requests and only goes back 5-10 minutes before all 1500 lines of logs run out.

Is there a way to check why the app crashed? If not, is there a way to make sure if it happens in the future I can catch the error somehow or at least know what happened?

P.S. My app is written in PHP and I'm using the basic free account on Heroku.

Answer (score 1):

I would try installing a free heroku logging add-on like Papertrail or loggly. Either one of them provides additional log storage which should be enough to see what happened to crash your app.